# Functions that can be written as direct products of other functions; question about terminology and notation

Tags: products, set-theory

Let
$$f : X_0 \rightarrow Y_0, \;\;\; g:X_1 \rightarrow Y_1$$
and define that the "direct product" of $f$ and $g$ is a map
$$f \otimes g : (X_0 \times X_1) \rightarrow (Y_0 \times Y_1), \mbox{ such that } (f \otimes g)(x_0,x_1)=(f(x_0),g(x_1)).$$

Question 1. What is the standard terminology/notation for this concept?

Now given a function $h$, it's possible that $h$ has the property that there exist $f$ and $g$ such that
$$h = f \otimes g$$
Question 2. What is the name of this property?

Comment: What context are you working in? In additive categories I would denote this $\begin{pmatrix}f&0\\0&g\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I know this as the "product of two functions", since it is just the result of applying the product functor $- \times -: Set \times Set \to Set$ to a pair of functions/morphisms. 

Comment: This condition comes up often enough for it really to deserve a name.  I never found a standard one and so have used the phrase "$h$ splits multiplicatively" in publications.  Despite its apparent simplicity it is useful to have criteria which one can use to determine if $h$ has this property.  Two very straightforward  ones which are valid under suitable assumptions are:
a) for all pairs $x_0$, $x_1$ and $y_0$, $y_1$ we have:
$h(x_0,x_0)h(x_1,y_1)=h(x_0,y_1)h(x_1,y_0)$. 
b)  $h h_{xy} = h_x h_y$ (this for smooth functions).

Comment: It is Cartesian product of two functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_product_of_functions

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that a map $F:\prod_{i=1}^n X_i \to \prod_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is **diagonal** if there are functions $f_i:X_i\to Y_i$ such that
$$ F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \bigl( f_1(x_1),\ldots,f_n(x_n) \bigr). $$
I've also seen the map $F$ called **triangular** if there are maps $f_i:\prod_{j=1}^i X_j\to Y_i$ such that
$$ F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \bigl( f_1(x_1),f_2(x_1,x_2),f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)\ldots,f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \bigr). $$
The terminology comes from the fact that if $F$ is a linear map $F:K^n\to K^n$, then $F$ is given by a diagonal, respectively (upper) triangular, matrix if the map $F$ is diagonal, respectively triangular. In the case that $Y_i=X_i$, both diagonal maps and triangular maps have been studied in dynamical systems.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1. It is Cartesian product of two functions, [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_product_of_functions).

Question 2. I think the second property may be called "two variables don't interfere", however I am unsure whether this phrase is well defined in mathematics.

Comment: I think it is more common to refer to separation of variables than to non-interfering variables.